# Web cam on RDS 2012 r2 clients?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2012-r2

My RDS clients (Win 8.1) needs to use Web Cam (in Lync) on their Win2012R2 RDS (Session Host).

How do I set this up?

I've found several of articles online, but they are all for Win2008R2. Is it still by using RemoteFX?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all, yes you still use RemoteFX and USB Device Redirection.  There have been some nice improvements for both of these in 2012, one of which is the isolation feature.  That should help your users do what they need to with their webcams.

[See this for how to setup RemoteFX](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx)

[See this for USB Device Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817581%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Make sure you note that Appendix A (from the USB Device Redirection Guide) does indeed say that 2012 redirection includes Webcams, but it is for LAN only.  Just FYI on that.

Please let me know if you get hung up along the way when setting this up and I'd be glad to help.